# How to know size of an array after passing it to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I have to know size of an array after passing it to a function. For example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(char *ptr)
{
     printf("%d\n",------); //Here i want the actual size of the array passed to ptr. What to fill in the blank to get total size of the arr[]
}
main()
{
    char arr[10] = "Hello";
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(arr));  // here it is giving 10 bytes that is equal to total size of the array
    func(arr);
}
```

Comment: You can't retrieve the size of an array from a pointer.  You need to either pass the array size as a separate argument or iterate over array elements until you find a sentinel value that marks the end (as happens for a `char*` string)

Comment: In C you should pass the size of an array to the function because in C there is only an address of the first element of an array passed.

Comment: That's the reason why so many function are with `size_t size` parameter.

Comment: Every one is saying same.... Which one should i accept?

Comment: @Chinna; `Every one is saying same.... Which one should i accept? `: Apply FCFS (first come first serve) algorithm in such situations. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, the compiler doesn't know that the pointer at the function is pointing to an array, there are some solutions though, I can state:

1) pass the length with the function parameters :

```
void func(char *ptr, int length)
{
    printf("%d\n",length);
}
```

2) if your array is always of type char, you can put a NULL char ('\0') and the use strlen

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *ptr)
{
    printf("%zu\n",strlen(ptr) + 1); 
}
int main()
{
    char arr[10] = {10,2,11,223,4,45,57,11, 12 ,'\0'};
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(arr));
    func(arr);
}
// prints 
//10
//10
```

Cheers

Comment: The proper format for printing values of type `size_t` (as returned by `sizeof` and `strlen()`) is `%zu`.

Comment: Thanks uwind, editing :)

Answer (score 2):

No way. You have to pass the size of array too. When you are passing an array to a function then actually you are passing pointer to its first element. In this case size of array is not known to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` decays into `pointers` when you pass to a function. With pointer alone, you can not get the size of the array. You have to pass one more argument to the calling function which is the `size` of the array.
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int myArray[10])
{
    int i = sizeof(myArray);
    printf("Size of myArray = %d\n", i);
}
int main(void)
{
    // Initialize all elements of myArray to 0
    int myArray[10] = {0}; 
    fun(myArray);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here the output will be 4 (depending on the sizeof pointer on your platform, it may vary)
This is because, `“arrays decays into pointers”` the compiler pretends that the array parameter was declared as a pointer and hence the size of pointer is printed.

So, you have to pass the size as one more parameter to the calling function...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int myArray[10], int size)
{
    printf("Size of myArray = %d\n", size);
}
int main(void)
{
    // Initialize all elements of myArray to 0
    int myArray[10] = {0}; 
    fun(myArray, sizeof(myArray));
    getchar();            ^----------------Here you are passing the size
    return 0;
}
```

So, here the output is 40...